# BaseHTTPRequestHandler doPOST method does not update html?

Tags: javascript, python, server

I am trying to get a simple local server going with python 3.6.

I start a HTTPServer and pass a BaseHTTPRequestHandler. The do_GET() method works fine. It servers a javascript file that executes a POST request.

The do_POST() method gets executed as "In post" is printed. However I do not see the output written to self.wfile.write() in the browser.

Am I missing something?

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import json

HOST, PORT = '', 8888
print("Serving HTTP on port %s." % PORT)


class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        """
        Respond to POST request.
        """

        print("In post")

        self.send_response(200)  # OK
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text')
        self.end_headers()

        cont = b"post"
        self.wfile.write(cont)

    def do_GET(self):
        """Respond to a GET request."""
        self.send_response(200)

        if self.path == "/":
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()
            path = "index.html"
        else:
            self.send_header("Content-type", "application/javascript")
            self.end_headers()
            path = self.path[1:]
        f = open(path, "rb")
        cont = f.read()
        self.wfile.write(cont)
        f.close()

http = HTTPServer((HOST, PORT), Handler)
http.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the POST request is being executed by a Javascript file, then presumably you are doing an Ajax request. That same JS script needs to actually do something with the response; the whole point of Ajax is that it doesn't refresh the page automatically.

Comment: Thanks! You were right. I called the post via $.post("/", data) and did not have a call back function.